# How to find the minimum of this constrained expression?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Let $x$, $y$, $z$ be three nonegative real numbers and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 5.$ Find the minimum of the expression
$$E=\dfrac{1}{2}x^2 y^2 + y^2 z^2 + z^2 x^2 + \dfrac{96}{x + y + z + 1}.$$
I tried

```
Minimize[{1/2 x^2 y^2 + y^2 z^2 + z^2 x^2 + 96/(x + y + z + 1), 
  x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 5}, {x, y, z}]
```

What should I do find the minimum of this expression?

Comment: Are you the same person that posted the same problem [here](http://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/146396-How-To-Find-The-Minimum-Value-Of-This-Expression)? Is this some kind of homework?

Comment: Your code returns the correct answer in v9.0.1, albeit a little slowly. (Less than 3 min. on my computer.)

Comment: @belisarius I am a teacher. I only want check my problem.

Comment: My problem is Minimize[{1/2 (x^2 y^2 + y^2 z^2 + z^2 x^2) + 96/(x + y + z + 1), x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 5}, {x, y, z}]. But I typed wrong.

Comment: @minthao_2011 `NMinimize[{1/2 (x^2 y^2 + y^2 z^2 + z^2 x^2) + 96/(x + y + z + 1), 
  x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 5}, {x, y, z}]` :D

Comment: @belisarius I did so. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about using a [Lagrange multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) to reduce the optimization problem to one target function and then use `Reduce` or `Solve`, to find the local maxima and minima. This gives you analytic expressions and you just have to select the one which is the smallest:

```
expr1 = 1/2 x^2 y^2 + y^2 z^2 + z^2 x^2 + 96/(x + y + z + 1);
expr2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 5;
lagrangian = expr1 + l*expr2
```

$$l \left(x^2+y^2+z^2-5\right)+\frac{x^2 y^2}{2}+x^2
   z^2+\frac{96}{x+y+z+1}+y^2 z^2$$

Now you calculate the partial derivatives and solve for the roots

```
problem = Flatten[{Thread[D[lagrangian, {{x, y, z, l}}] == 0], x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}];
sol = Solve[problem, {x, y, z, l}];
```

`sol` contains now the analytic solutions. You could now put the numerical values into `E` and into the constraints and see that the constraints are indeed fulfilled.

```
{expr1, expr2} /. N[sol]
(*
{{25.5712, 8.88178*10^-16}, 
 {26.963, 1.42553*10^-13}, 
 {24.9556, -1.72706*10^-12}, 
 {24.6693, 2.04281*10^-14}, 
 {24.6693, 1.66543*10^-10}}
*)
```

You see, that you get the additional symmetric solution belisarius was speaking about in his answer.

```
N[sol[[4]]]
(* {x -> 0.879965, y -> 2.00209, z -> 0.466144, l -> 0.663595} *)
```

Note that you have the solution given as large analytic expressions but they are too large to post them here.

Comment: @belisarius Sorry, haven't seen that. Nevertheless, one *has* to make them instead of getting everything from the solution.

Comment: It's odd that `Minimize` does not seem to do this even if you box in the domain with `0 <= x <= Sqrt[5]` etc.  The [refs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationExact.html#248466559) suggest it would use Lagrange multipliers, but it ran for an hour before I gave up, as opposed to half a second for yours.

Answer (score 7):

Use a numerical approach:

```
NMinimize[{1/2 x^2 y^2 + y^2 z^2 + z^2 x^2 + 96/(x + y + z + 1), 
           x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 5}, {x, y, z}]

{24.6693, {x -> 2.00209, y -> 0.879965, z -> 0.466144}}
```

By symmetry considerations exchanging x and y will give the same minimum.

Comment: How about exact answer?

Comment: @minthao_2011 You haven't required that in your question. Please try to be very precise in your requirements so our time is well spent.

Comment: I am sory. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a similar approach as @halirutan together with spherical coordinates to take care of one constraint and remove the need for multipliers.

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = 1/2 x^2 y^2 + y^2 z^2 + z^2 x^2 + 96/(x + y + z + 1);

r = Sqrt[5];
subs = {x -> r Sin[t] Cos[f], y -> r Sin[t] Sin[f], z -> r Cos[t]};
constr = {x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0, 0 <= t <= Pi, 0 <= f <= 2 Pi} /. subs ;

g[t_, f_] = f[x, y, z] /. subs ;

allSolutions = Solve[Join[Thread[Grad[g[t, f], {t, f}] == 0], constr], {t, f}] ;

possibleResults = {N[#], subs /. N[#], g[t, f] /. N[#]} & /@ allSolutions ;

Select[possibleResults, #[[3]] ==  Min[possibleResults[[All, 3]]] &][[All, 2 ;;]]
(* {{{x -> 2.00209, y -> 0.879965, z -> 0.466144}, 24.6693}, 
    {{x -> 0.879965, y -> 2.00209, z -> 0.466144}, 24.6693}} *)
```

You can remove `N` from the first entry in `possibleResults` to get the analytical solution.